# Replace a placeholder with text from database

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, ajax

I'm trying to figure out the best practice to achieve my desired results. I have tried searching the internet but can't figure out the correct terminology to figure out a solution.

I have several websites that I manage. I have pricing that spans these websites, I would like to update the price across all of the websites at once. I am building a backend system to change the price across all of the websites.

Currently, the websites are hosted on Weebly. I can only use Javascript to parse the HTML then replace the information.

I was thinking of using custom HTML tags as a placeholder. For example: `<price attributeOne="info" attributeTwo="info" />` or curly brackets `{{attributeone:info, atrributetwo:info}}` or even HTML comments `<!-- attribute:value -->`

I don't want the Javascript to take a lot of time parsing the document because there cannot be any noticeable delay. I would then make an ajax request to my external server, get the information, and send it back to replace the placeholder.

Also, if there are multiple prices on one page, what would be the best way to get the information and send it back in one request.

I appreciate any help I can get, or even someone to point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a templating engine like ejs or jade or handlebars and you can easily replace your placeholder with custom one first you will get the required data from your database to your js file and then send the data to ejs using <% %> these for more detailed info refer ejs documentation here

https://ejs.co/#docs